# How to insert radio button, checkbox and other input types into jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, eclipse-orion

Why can't I insert into table with error message "cannot find symbol (JSP page line 8)". I have tried so many things like change from array to variable. I am using Orion Application Server 2.0.7 with jdk 1.6

The error message:

```
Syntax error in source
/a/submitted.jsp.java:35:  cannot find symbol (JSP page line 8)

symbol  : method getParameterValue(java.lang.String)

location: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

  String skill[] = request.getParameterValue("skill");
                          ^

1 error
```

**Register.jsp**

```
 <html>
        <head>
        <title> Pendaftaran</title> 
        <style> 
        #myDIV {
            width: 1500px;
            height: 800px;
            background: white;
            animation: mymove 5s infinite;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
            from {background-color: #3CB5B5;}
            to {background-color: #FCD920;}
            to {background-color: #E53B51;}
            to {background-color: #EC6C20;}
        }
        button{ background: white; width:150px; height: 50px; font-size: 30px }
        input{ background: white; width:150px; height: 40px; font-size: 30px }
        p{background: white; font-size: 5}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm()
            {
            var x=document.mydata.ID.value;
            var y=document.mydata.Name.value;
            var z0=document.mydata.sex[0].checked;
            var z1=document.mydata.sex[1].checked;
            var a0=document.mydata.skill[0].checked ;
            var a1=document.mydata.skill[1].checked ;
            var a2=document.mydata.skill[2].checked ;
            var c=document.mydata.major.selectedIndex;
            if (((a0==false) && (a1==false) && (a2==false))||x==null || x==""||y==null || y==""|| c==0||((z0==false)&&(z1==false)))
              {
              alert("There is still unfilled data!");
              return false;
              }
            }

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>  
        <div id="myDIV">
        <br><center><h1>SSK3408 SYSTEM</h1></center></br>
        <hr>    
        <body style="background: #d8d8d8; color: White">
            <br>

            <form name="mydata" action="submitted.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <table border="0">
            <tr>
              <td><h1>Student ID: </td>
              <td><h1><input type="text" name="ID"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h1>Name:</td>
              <td><h1><input type="text" name="Name"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h1>Gender :</td>
              <td><h1><input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="male" /> Male
                      <input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h1>Skill :</td>
              <td><h1><input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="C++"> C++<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="Java"> Java<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="Phyton"> Phyton
                  <br></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
              <td><h1>Major :</td>
              <td><h1><select name="major">
                <option value="">Please select here :</option>
                  <option value="Software Enginnering">Software Enginnering</option>
                  <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
                  <option value="Network">Network</option>
                  <option value="Multimedia">Multimedia</option>
                  </select></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>

              <td><h1></td>
              <td><h1></td>
              <td><h1></td>
              <td><h1><br><button type="button"onclick="location.href='Registration.jsp"><strong>Reset</strong></button></td>

              <td><h1><br><button type="submit"><strong>Submit</strong></button></td>

              <td><h1><br><button type="button"onclick="location.href='MainMenu.jsp'"><strong>Back</strong></button></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

**submitted.jsp**

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
                                <%
                                //Create an empty new variable 
                                  String message = null;
                                  String ID = request.getParameter("ID");
                                  String name = request.getParameter("Name");
                                  //String male = request.getParameter("sex");
                                  String gender = request.getParameter("sex");
                                  String skill = request.getParameterValue("skill");
                                  //String skillJ = request.getParameter("skillJ");
                                  //String skillP = request.getParameter("skillP");
                                  String major = request.getParameter("major");


                                  //CONNECTION initiator
                                  PreparedStatement stmt = null;
                                  Connection conn = null;   
                                  try {
                                              //Connect to the database
                                              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                                              String hostname = "172.16.60.13";
                                              int port = 1521;
                                              String sid = "orcl";
                                              String oracleURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+hostname+":"+port+":"+sid;
                                              String user = "C180495";
                                              String pass = "180495";
                                              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(oracleURL, user, pass);
                                              // Make the query
                                              stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into STUDENTS values(?,?,?,?)");
                                              stmt.clearParameters();
                                              stmt.setString(1,ID);
                                              stmt.setString(2,name);
                                              stmt.setString(3,gender);
                                              stmt.setString(4,major);

                                              //Run the query
                                              stmt.executeUpdate();

                                              for(int i = 0; i<4;i++){

                                              stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into skill values(?,?)");
                                              stmt.clearParameters();
                                              stmt.setString(1,ID);
                                              stmt.setString(2,skill[i]);
                                               out.println("<p><b> SQL ERROR </b></p><p>" + skill[i]+ "</p>");
                                              stmt.executeUpdate();

                                            }

                                              conn.commit();
                                              out.println("<p> <b> You have been registered !</b></p>");

                                              //Close the database connection
                                              stmt.close();
                                              conn.close();
                                    } catch (SQLException ex) {   
                                   out.println("<p><b> SQL ERROR </b></p><p>" + ex.getMessage()+ "</p>");
                                   stmt.close();
                                   conn.close();
                                 } 

                                %>
```

Comment: Please include code *in the post*, not offsite links to file shares of code. This helps us to help you, because we can easily copy the code to try it ourselves, and it helps search engines index the question properly for future readers.

Comment: Such issues occur when there is a syntax error in your jsp. Share your code

Comment: I don't know how to add, I am new to here, still not found so many features on this website

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a method called `getParameterValue` on the `request` object, and that method doesn't exist.

You're looking for the method [`getParameterValues`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) (it ends in an 's', it's plural) on interface `HttpServletRequest`.

However the code that you later posted for your JSP is inconsistent with your error message, so you must have changed your code.

In the JSP error, your line of code reads:

```
String skill[] = request.getParameterValue("skill");
```

But in the JSP that you posted the line reads: (without the `[]` behind `skill`)

```
String skill = request.getParameterValue("skill");
```

If you just want one value in a single String, instead of all values in an array, then you should call the method `getParameter`, so you change your code to:

```
String skill = request.getParameter("skill");
```

If you want all values in an array, you change your code to:

```
String skill[] = request.getParameterValues("skill");
```

Comment: I have just editted my question, Can you help me again? I don't get what you mean. Please help me repair the code for me

Comment: as you mention I change from 
String skill = request.getParameterValue("skill") to
String[] skill = request.getParameterValues("skill");
 is that what you mean?

Comment: I was just success doing the insertion but I use tomcat server instead of orion